# Selecting Multiple Checkbox in Selenium

Tags: jquery, selenium, xpath, checkbox

I'm new to selenium and I'm trying to select group of check boxes were i used to fetch the check box with

```
List WebElement studyFund = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[type='checkbox']"));
```

In this list there is a bulk checkbox with 150 and separated in each tabs. When using type='checkbox' were it fetch the details of all the checkbox text.

Now, I need to select one by one from each tabs that too in random on the group

Eg: Tab1 having checkbox with 10
Tab2 having checkbox with 15
Tab3 having checkbox with 30-70 which separated in sub division.

But, I need to select the Tab1 checkbox in random. I don't know how to use the selection from the 1st Tab check box and move next.

Any one help me how to apply with selenium webdriver.

Comment: you will have to find tabs one by one and then checkboxes..

Comment: Can you provide the hmtl as well?